# Hello world not working. Function not found

Tags: solidity, truffle

I have a simple test contract that I've deployed using truffle:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract TestObject {

  uint public myValue;

    function TextObject() {
        myValue = 1000;
    }

  function deposit(uint value) returns(uint) {
        myValue += value;
        return myValue;
    }
}
```

If I do

```
var ob = TestObject.deployed();

ob
```

I can see that my object has been deployed:

```
.
.
.
 myValue: 
   { [Function]
     call: [Function],
     sendTransaction: [Function],
     request: [Function: bound ],
     estimateGas: [Function] },
  TextObject: 
   { [Function]
     call: [Function],
     sendTransaction: [Function],
     request: [Function: bound ],
     estimateGas: [Function] },
  deposit: 
   { [Function]
     call: [Function],
     sendTransaction: [Function],
     request: [Function: bound ],
     estimateGas: [Function] },
  sendTransaction: [Function],
  send: [Function],
  allEvents: [Function: bound ],
  address: '0xe43d2d9d7d0cb6d13100ded5548a78139d479047',
  transactionHash: null }
```

Also myValue seems to be present.

When I call `ob.myValue` I get undefined

If I try to set the value:

```
ob.deposit(23);
```

I get:

```
TypeError: ob.deposit is not a function
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:1:4
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInContext (vm.js:35:29)
    at Object.runInContext (vm.js:89:6)
    at TruffleInterpreter.interpret (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:209587:17)
    at bound (domain.js:280:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:538:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:233:10)
```

Anyone know whats going on here?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT** 
Here's my deployment code in migrations/2_deploy_contracts.js:

```
var Adoption = artifacts.require("./Adoption.sol");
var TestObject = artifacts.require("./TestObject.sol");
const Storage = artifacts.require("./Storage.sol");


module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Adoption);
  deployer.deploy(TestObject);
  deployer.deploy(Storage);

};
```

Comment: Are you testing against testrpc? Did you restart testrpc? Can you share what are you doing between `ob = TestObject.deployed()` and `ob.deposit(23)`? How do you get `myValue` from the contract? It should be `const val = ob.myValue()`.

Comment: Yeah I restarted testrpc. I don't do anything between those calls. const val = ob.myValue() gives the same error: ob.myValue is not a function. Is there any other information I can give that could help?

Comment: That is the problem, testrpc by default will start a new blockchain when it is restarted. You have to re-deploy your contracts with `truffle migrate --reset`. Or start testrpc in persistent mode `testrpc --db mydir/ -d` (First create an empty dir `mkdir mydir`). `--db` is where testrpc will store its blockchain, next invocation will start where you left, `-d` generates the same address in each invocation [more about testrpc options](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc/).

Comment: Truffle stores the deployed address in the contract artifacts inside the `build/` directory, and will it use when needed. If the blockchains has been restarted then there will be no contract at that addres, and it will fail like in your case, `deployed()` returns undefined because there's no code at the contract address.

Comment: @Ismael I restarted testrpc, then truffle migrate --reset. There are in fact .json artifacts present in /build. But unfortunately still no luck.

Comment: It returns the same error or something different? Truffle returns promises so it will not return the value immediately, you have to await (node v8), or chain to another promise with `.then()`. In node v8 `const ob = await TestObject.deployed();` or in node v6 `var ob; TestObject.deployed().then((res) => { ob = res; return ob.myValue.call(); }).then((val) => { console.log(val); })`

Comment: @Ismael yeah it never returns the promise. I just get errors. For example: obj.myValue.call(); causes: TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Comment: I've put an example that works but requires node v8 https://gist.github.com/ismaelbej/0b976a87576c4d068fb9552764996a49

Comment: @Ismael I tried copying your code exactly and included my 2_deploy_contracts.js above in an edit. Unfortunately calling Storage functions returns TypeError: storage.setUserData is not a function

Comment: @Ismael Your test file worked though... and yet var storage = Storage.deployed(); returns undefined in the console and gives "not a function" errors

Comment: From the console you can use `.then` because deployed returns a promise. `var storage; Storage.deplyed().then((res) => { storage = res; })`. After that you can write to storage `storage.setUserData(1, 1)` and read data with `storage.getUserData(1).then((res) => console.log(res))`

Comment: @Ismael Yay! it worked. I guess it was returning a promise after all and i didn't realize it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that the contract was not deployed properly or that you don't have the contract instance object and there isn't much information to be able tell what exactly went wrong in the process. Try to re-deploy your contract using the following steps (in the node console) and see what happens:

```
Web3 = require('web3')
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
code = fs.readFileSync('/path/to/contract/TestObject.sol').toString()
solc = require('solc')
compiledCode = solc.compile(code)
abiDefinition = JSON.parse(compiledCode.contracts[':TestObject'].interface)
TestContract = web3.eth.contract(abiDefinition)
byteCode = compiledCode.contracts[':TestObject'].bytecode
deployedContract = TestContract.new({data: byteCode, from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas: 45000000})
contractInstance = TestContract.at(deployedContract.address)
```

Obviously, make sure that you have either testrpc/geth running on localhost, port 8545.

Lastly, you can play around with the `contractInstance` object to invoke functions.

```
contractInstance.deposit(200, {from: web.eth.accounts[0]});
contractInstance.myValue.call() // public variables get getter functions by default
```

Comment: Thanks! I executed all the commands fine except the last one.  I get Error: Invalid address passed to TestObject.at(): undefined. When examining deployedContract it appears to have a valid address... is there any information I can give you that would help? Im still pretty confused...

Comment: Notice that you are naming the contract as TestObject but the constructor's name is TeXtObject. This might not be the cause of your error, but anyways you'll have to fix it. Otherwise myValue will never be initialized at 1000.

Comment: Oh good catch. Unfortunately I seem to have the same issue...

Comment: @RichardGarfield I think I had a bug in my code, too! `TestObject.at()` should be `TestContract.at()`. I have made the changes in my code above. Can you try now and see what happens? Can you see if `deployedContract.address` and `contractInstance` objects are finely constructed?

Comment: @MananMehta I was able to get your code to work, but I'm not sure what the next step is? Thank you again.

Comment: @RichardGarfield I'm not sure if I understand. Did I not answer your question? Can you call `contractInstance.deposit()` and `contractInstance.myValue.call()`? Do you mind clarifying what your question is and I'll be happy to help :)

Comment: @MananMehta It seems that you're creating a second instance of TestObject manually for testing purposes. When I run truffle migrate that should have already created a previous instance of TestObject, but for some reason the console can't find it? If truffle migrate can't actually create TestObject I don't see how I can deploy a real app. Hope that made sense, I'm still pretty confused.

Comment: @RichardGarfield Sorry, I wasn't aware that you were using Truffle. I haven't used Truffle actually (but you can deploy it the way I deployed it and just host a separate webapp that interacts with that contract through metamask). Let me go home and have a look and see if I can be of any help